# Convert ushort array to bit array

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I have a ushort array:

```
ushort[] testArray = new ushort[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

How I can convert it to a bit Array. In the above example, a length of  `5 * 16` bit array? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why did you write `5*16` bit array? You don't know `int` is wrapped over `Int32`, not `Int16`, don't you?

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped. The source array is `ushort`.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple google search gives this [BitArray Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray(v=vs.110).aspx)

Example

```
using System.Collections;

int[]  myInts  = new int[5] { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
BitArray myBA5 = new BitArray( myInts );
```

**Update:**

So I was interested in the problem and decided to complete a working solution. This is what I'd do to handle shorts. One thing though is I'm assuming the bits will still translate given that you aren't trying to re-interperate back (??) and just want to loop through the raw bits?

```
var shorts = new ushort[] { 5, 1 };
var numberOfInts = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)shorts.Length / 2);
var theInts = new int[numberOfInts];

var shortsPos = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfInts; i++)
{   
    theInts[i] = shorts[shortsPos + 1];
    theInts[i] = theInts[i] | ((int)shorts[shortsPos] << 16);
    shortsPos =+ 2;
    //theInts[i].Dump();
}

var bitArr = new BitArray(theInts);
foreach (var bit in bitArr)
{
    //bit.Dump();
}
```

I mocked this up in LinqPad hence the .Dump() statements so do you're own thing for testing.  You may have to switch around the order and maybe shift the second in each pair...I'll leave that part for you to work out.  Also if you just have a single value in your source ushort[] you'll get an error so work out the maths to sort that out too..

The result of the above is:

```
True
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
True
False
True
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
```

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped. The source array is ushort

Comment: So ushort is 16 bit. BitArray takes int (32bit). You need to mash the two ushorts together.  Set your target to the value as the second ushort and bitwise shift the first one left 16 bits then bitwise or them together.  Do this for all the ushorts, if you have four you'll have two ints, five you'll have 3 ints (still bitwise shift the fifth to the left.  Then pass the ints in as I've described.

Comment: Thanks for your effort!

Comment: I ran it tweaked switching around the ordering so shifting the second of the pairs and it comes out right. The enumerator on BitArray runs the lowest bit to highest - right to left.

Answer (score 0):

```
            int[] testArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            Dictionary<int, int[]> convertData = new Dictionary<int, int[]>();

            foreach (int x in testArray)
            {
                System.Collections.BitArray b = new System.Collections.BitArray(Convert.ToByte(x));
                convertData[x] = b.Cast<bool>().Select(bit => bit ? 1 : 0).ToArray();
            }
```